# Clojure infinite lazy sequences, out of bounds

Tags: clojure, sequence, lazy-evaluation

I've only recently started learning Clojure, so apologies if this is a little elementary:

Can somebody please explain to me the difference between:

```
=> (def a (lazy-cat
            [0]
            (map inc a)
   ))

=> (take 5 a)
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

and

```
=> (def b (lazy-cat
            [0]
            (map #(inc (nth b %)) (range))
   ))

=> (take 5 b)

IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:773)
```

I expected the second example to function in the same way, using the first element of b to calculate the second, then the second to calculate the third. My understanding was that clojure wouldn't even attempt to calculate the third element of b until it had already assigned a value to the second element and printed it on the screen.

I'd appreciate an explanation somebody could give about what's actually going on behind the scenes here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is `map` function implementation for simplest `(map f colls)` case. See the difference:

```
user=> (def b (lazy-cat [0] (map (fn [i _] (inc (nth b i))) (range) (range))))
#'user/b
user=> (take 5 b)
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

It's little bit confusing, but let me explain what's going on. So, why second argument to `map` changes behavior:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2469

```
(defn map
  ...
  ([f coll]
   (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (if (chunked-seq? s)
        (let [c (chunk-first s)
              size (int (count c))
              b (chunk-buffer size)]
          (dotimes [i size]
              (chunk-append b (f (.nth c i))))
              (chunk-cons (chunk b) (map f (chunk-rest s))))
        (cons (f (first s)) (map f (rest s)))))))
  ([f c1 c2]
   (lazy-seq
    (let [s1 (seq c1) s2 (seq c2)]
      (when (and s1 s2)
        (cons (f (first s1) (first s2))
              (map f (rest s1) (rest s2)))))))
...
```

Answer: cause of optimization for `chunked-seq`.

```
user=> (chunked-seq? (seq (range)))
true
```

So, values will be "precalculated":

```
user=> (def b (lazy-cat [0] (map print (range))))
#'user/b
user=> (take 5 b)
(0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930310 nil nil nil nil)
```

And off course, in your case this "precalculation" fails with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Just realised I forgot to ever thank you. This was a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of `take`:

```
(defn take
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the first n items in coll, or all items if
  there are fewer than n."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [n coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (pos? n) 
     (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (first s) (take (dec n) (rest s)))))))
```

Now run through that for the first case. There's no chance to address an array out of bounds.

For your second example, you are calling `nth` on a sequence that hasn't been expanded to n elements yet. b will try to concatenate 0 with a sequence that depends on an element that doesn't exist.